# XML XSD - Allowing arbitrary grand children elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to create an XSD schema in which only the root element and its immediate child is policed by the XSD. In other words I want to allow arbitrary grand-children of the root element while root element and children elements are strictly validated by the XSD.
So if I have

```
<text>
   <language>
    ...
   </language>
</text>
```

It should enforce the presence of text and language but impose no restriction what sort of XML tags I add below the level of .

Is that possible at all? I have used XSD but not to great extent and cannot find a reference, neither stating I can do it, nor that it is forbidden to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**xsd:any**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-1-20010502/#declare-openness) at the grandchild level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">
  <xs:element name="text">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="language">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:any/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>  
</xs:schema>
```

Other considerations:

- Adjust the cardinality constraints (`minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`) per
  your needs.
- Add `mixed="true"` for mixed content (text and elements) per your
  needs.